# How to calculate the sum of rows in group only when the condition is met

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame similar to this:

```
data.frame(Group1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A"),
           Group2 = c("X", "X", "X", "Y"),
           ValueA = c(20, 40, 50, 80),
           ValueB = c(0, 0, 70, 60))
```

I want to calculate the sum of rows in `ValueA` within group by `Group1` and `Group2`, only when value in `ValueB` is 0.

My expected output is:

```
data.frame(Group1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A"),
           Group2 = c("X", "X", "X", "Y"),
           ValueA = c(20, 40, 50, 80),
           ValueB = c(0, 0, 70, 60),
           SumA_whenBis0 = c(60, 60, 0, 0))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use a `grouped_by` `mutate` and only sum `ValueA`  when `ValueB == 0` by subsetting it `sum(ValueA[ValueB == 0])`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df <-  data.frame(Group1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A"),
             Group2 = c("X", "X", "X", "Y"),
             ValueA = c(20, 40, 50, 80),
             ValueB = c(0, 0, 70, 60))

df %>% 
  group_by(Group1, Group2) %>% 
  mutate(SumA_whenBis0 = sum(ValueA[ValueB == 0]))

#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#> # Groups:   Group1, Group2 [2]
#>   Group1 Group2 ValueA ValueB SumA_whenBis0
#>   <chr>  <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>         <dbl>
#> 1 A      X          20      0            60
#> 2 A      X          40      0            60
#> 3 A      X          50     70            60
#> 4 A      Y          80     60             0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>